# How to improve performance on counting columns in a matrix which are below a threshold?

Tags: r, performance, matrix

In my code I am subtracting one column of a matrix from every other column of the same matrix.
Then I count how many of the new columns have only elements that are smaller than `r`.
I'm doing this for each column of the matrix. You can see my code below. I left out the part where I put values into the matrix.

Is there any way to improve the performance of this code? I can't seem to figure out a way to make this faster

```
B = matrix(NA,(m),(window_step))
B_m_r = c(1:(window_step))

for (i in 1:(window_step)){
    B_m_r[i] = sum(apply(abs(B[,-i]-B[,i]), 2,function(x) max(x) < r))
}
```

### Solution

```
B = matrix(NA,(m),(window_step))
B_m_r = c(1:(window_step))
buffer_B = matrix(NA,(window_step-1),(window_step-1))

for (i in 1:(window_step-2)){
    buffer_B[i,c(i:(window_step-1))] = apply(abs(B[,-c(1:i)]-B[,i]),2,function(x) max(x) < r)
    B_m_r[i] = (sum(buffer_B[i,c(i:(window_step-1))])+sum(buffer_B[1:i,i]))
}

B_m_r[window_step] = sum(buffer_B[1:(window_step-1),(window_step-1)])
B_m_r[window_step-1] =  sum(buffer_B[1:(window_step-2),(window_step-2)])
```

Ok so based on the help from Яaffael I found a solution, that doesn't calculate the differences twice.

Instead I save the result of the comparison with `r` from previous loops in the matrix `buffer_B` and use them for the next loop to calculate the sum of all columns who are smaller than `r`.

Now the code takes only half the time to finish.
Thanks!

Comment: how about simplifying your code and removing the special cases. f.x. you cannot subtract A and B columnwise because they don't have the same number of rows (of course you handle that somehow). this clutter just keeps you and me from getting a clear picture.

Comment: @Яaffael I am taking one column of B and subtract it from every other column in B. Then I do the same for A. Perhaps that wasn't clear? I edited the first sentence of the question to clarify that. The number of rows doesn't matter, right? The more rows the longer it takes but that's it.

Comment: okay great, but then my question would be - why have twice the same calculation when one would be enough to make the point clear. the shorter the code the higher the chance that somebody takes time to think about it. Also window_step could be removed I think. It might be relevant for your specific implementation but not for this question.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Sorry, first time that I posted a question myself and not just searched for answers;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **for example** reduce the calculation time by 50% by only checking "< r" for half of the column differences because they are effectively symmetric.

You are calculating abs(first of B - last of B) and abs(last of B - first of B).

**PLUS** you can precalculate the handled difference matrix instead of using a for loop to set it up step by step.

```
# I am using single-row matrices to keep it simple

> A <- matrix(1:4,ncol=4)

> A[,1:ceiling(ncol(A)/2)]
[1] 1 2

> A[,ncol(A):(floor(ncol(A)/2)+1)]
[1] 4 3

> A <- matrix(1:5,ncol=5)

> A[,1:ceiling(ncol(A)/2)]
[1] 1 2 3

> A[,ncol(A):(floor(ncol(A)/2)+1)]
[1] 5 4 3

> abs(A[,1:ceiling(ncol(A)/2)] - A[,ncol(A):(floor(ncol(A)/2)+1)])
[1] 4 2 0
```

When you want to speed up code in R then first thing you should try is to turn all loops into vectorized expressions using R functions. A loop will run within R. Vectorized function calls allow R to execute essentially compiled C code.

Comment: Yes, I am checking everything two times. My solution would then be to replace `abs(B[,-i]-B[,i])` with `abs(B[,-c(1:i)]-B[,i])`. But i need the number of "abs" columns that are smaller than `r` for each original column.

Comment: For example. For i=1 I check (B[,2]-B[,1]), (B[,3]-B[,1]) so on and so forth. But for i = 2 I wouldn't check (B[,1]-B[,2]) but i need to know if its smaller or greater than `r` for the sum in B_m_r[2]

Comment: I would need to precalculate one difference matrix for every loop cycle, because in every for loop I subtract one column from **every** other column to create the difference matrix. `abs(B[,-i] - B[,i])` creates a whole matrix, where the column `B[,i]` is subtracted from every column of B except for `B[,i]`.